# Any way to efficiently sync two databases?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am planning to make a software which requires two or more databases to be in sync with a main server database ( located on a web server ). Suppose one user have installed my software on more than one computers. Suppose he updates some info on PC-1 then the change should be locally updated and if he is connected with the internet, it should get in sync with the main web server. When he opens the software on PC-2, latest into must be shown there ( assuming he is connected with the internet ).

Now suppose both PC-1 and PC-2 have same data, and both are offline. User deletes the data from PC-1 but don't deletes it from PC-2 ( he assumes it'll get managed automatically ), now when both of the systems go online, the record must be deleted from PC-2 too.

Basically, I am trying to find the database which was most recently updated or modified and sync it with the main database ( on the server ). How can I do it ?

Comment: What type of data do you need to sync, and how big is it? This sounds like an excellent use-case for [Amazon Cognito Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) or [AWS AppSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/welcome.html). They can synchronize user data, which is probably closer to what you want to do rather than "synchronizing databases".

Comment: for now data will be mostly text

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to synchronize some user data whenever the users or application becomes "online" again.

A couple of suitable services are:

- [Amazon Cognito Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) is an AWS service and client library that enables cross-device syncing of application-related user data. You can use it to synchronize user profile data across mobile devices and the web without requiring your own backend. The client libraries cache data locally so your app can read and write data regardless of device connectivity status. When the device is online, you can synchronize data, and if you set up push sync, notify other devices immediately that an update is available.
- [AWS AppSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/welcome.html) enables developers to interact with their data by using a managed GraphQL service. GraphQL offers many benefits over traditional gateways, encourages declarative coding style, and works seamlessly with modern tools and frameworks, including React, React Native, iOS, and Android. [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) is a data language that was developed to enable apps to fetch data from servers. It has a declarative, self-documenting style. In a GraphQL operation, the client specifies how to structure the data when it is returned by the server. This makes it possible for the client to query only for the data it needs, in the format that it needs it in.